# Troubles with outline on cubes

Tags: shaders, npr

I am working on a project that requires me to have outlines on cubes, the outline HAS to be a shader, not matter if it's a combination of nodes or a script,it has to be a shader. Meaning that I can't add extra-mesh like the solidify modifier would do.

And I couldn't find any way to do outlines on a sharp cube with nodes, every single way I saw to do it was with smooth objects. The project I'm working on will be NPR, and I want to render on my GPU to minimize render time.

Here is a mockup of what I want to do, you can see all of the objects in the scene have their outline visible, and only the **OUT**-lines

[image: mockup]

The outline also has to be able to take a texture's color, so the solodify modifier is NOT an option (I said it already but I want it to be clear). Here is a mockup of how it would look

[image]

Hope this was precise and well explained enough.

EDIT : Freestyle is NOT an option.

Comment: I know you said you need a shader, but Freestyle plus the compositor could do exactly what you want. Is that an option?

Comment: @hekete it's not an option, I need it to be a shader, the compositor doesn't produce a good enough result. plus freestyle has a lot of problems rendering outlines.

Comment: I would say freestyle is pretty good at rendering outlines these days... Any way I think you will have to write a GLSL shader to do what you want otherwise.

Comment: @hekete I had some troubles with freestyle, even in 2.8.
And yeah, that's why I precised "node or code" shader.

Comment: @hekete to clarify my last answer : no I won't be using freestyle, I didn't precise "shader" to use freestyle, I won't use it because it's not good enough for what I'm looking for.

Comment: About the textures, how are they supposed to be mapped to the meshes? I mean, the standard way or flatten as if meshes were flat inside the outlines?

Comment: And another question: is it cube only meshes?

Comment: @lemon yes it's only cube geometry, and the texture will use UVs, that's part of why I need it to be a material / shader

Comment: @azagwen, is coding some event handler (render_pre, render_post for instance) an option?

Comment: @lemon can you tell me more about this ? Yes coding is an option as long as it's usable in a script node or something similar.

EDIT : even creating a custom node is an option, it just has to be a shader.